# what is differnce between git filters on UI and git rev-list command

Tags: git, github, git-filter

I am trying to analyse the number of commits done on my master branch. I found two ways, one is on applying filters on git UI and other via git CLI. I got the different output by both the commands. The outputs are as-

> ON UI-
>     `is:pr is:merged merged:>=2018-05-20`

I got output as **81** Total. And when I try to get the output via CLI using the below command-

> Using git CLI-
>     `git rev-list --count HEAD --since="Sep 05 2018"`

o/p is-  **230** total.

As per my understanding both of these commands should produce same output. Or is there any difference between them ??
**Note:- No direct commit on master is allowed.**

Comment: All of the commits that got merged are considered to be on master, not just the merge commits themselves. You could try searching commit summaries for /^Merge pull request/ as a practical solution, though any commit *could* have its message set to that.

Answer (score 0):

`rev-list` has a whole bunch of filtering options, one of them is :

> ```
> --merges
>     Print only merge commits. This is exactly the same as --min-parents=2.
> ```

My guess is this is what `is:merged` applies.

---

*note* : do not forget the 's', `--merge` also exists, and does not do the same thing at all :

> ```
> --merge
>     After a failed merge, show refs that touch files having a conflict and
>     don’t exist on all heads to merge.
> ```

---

Thinking about it : github's pull requests are not represented in the git repo, I imagine `is:pr` would list those ; in that case, `is:merged` could also filter based on a flag in github's database, and not be something you could check easily through `git rev-list`.

Among your git merges, do you see some which obviously do not match a PR ?

Comment: may be you are right...I tried that I endup with different result. `On UI 84 ` and `using rev-list 113`. So, question still remain open..